# Zeroes in natural numbers up to a googol

Tags: mathematics

How many times does the digit $0$ occur in the list of numbers from $1$ to $10^{100}$, inclusive?

Comment: And list all the numbers in which it occurs... ;-)

Comment: hehe good luck with that :)

Comment: Are we considering leading zeros as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Observe that the numbers of occurrences of zeroes from $0$ to $10^n-1$ follow this sequence
>
>  0, 1, 10, 190, 2890, 38890, ... ([oeis](https://oeis.org/A033714))

> those numbers can be obtained for any $n > 2$ as
>
>  $10^{n-1} + \sum_{i=2}^{n-1} (10^{n-1}-10^{n-i})$
>  Where each summation member is the number of occurrences of the zeroes in the $i$-th position starting from right and $10^{n-1}$ is the count of zeroes in the first position.
>  
> ie. for $n=4$ we count all zeroes between 0 and 9999
>  
>  $10^3+(10^3-10^2) + (10^3-10) = 2890$

> plugging in $n=100$ we obtain:
>
>  $ 10^{99} + \sum_{i=2}^{99} (10^{99}-10^{100-i})$

> Now we have to move the range from $[0,10^n-1]$ to $[1,10^n]$. 
>  
>  To achieve this, we have to subtract the first zero count and add 100 zeroes from the googol itself to get the final answer:
>  $ 10^{99} + \sum_{i=2}^{99} (10^{99}-10^{100-i})$ - 1 + 100 = 98888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888989

Bonus

> To easily get the n-th entry (ignoring the first "$0$" term) of the OEIS serie above, for $n >= 3$ you can use this simple trick:
>
> - write $n - 2$
> - append $8$, $n-3$ times
> - append $90$
>  
>  for $n=100$ 
> - $98$ 
> - $8888.....8888$ (97 eights) 
> - $90$

Comment: Nice! Can you write the answer in closed form, just for clarity? Thanks.

Comment: It is easier to count all zeros (proper and leading) first: N x 10^(N-1) and then subtract leading zeros: 1+10+100+1000+... (N terms). (Add back 1 if you want to count 0 as a legit 0 even though it is leading.)

Comment: Great work and thanks for finding the sequence. There is actually a closed form formula in the OEIS, which you can use here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the last $100$ digits of each of these numbers, padded with leading zeroes as necessary.

> Now consider *reversing* each of these strings. Since we're counting all $10^{100}$ $100$-digit strings, this is a bijection, and it has the effect of *turning leading zeroes into trailing zeroes,* with the exception of the all-zeroes string we got from $10^{100}$. Therefore, the trailing zeroes that we wish to count are half of all the zeroes, plus the other $50$ from the all-zeroes string.
>  Each position in the string has a $0$ in exactly one-tenth of the strings each, and there are $100$ positions, so the total zeroes are $\frac{\frac{10^{100}}{10}100}{2}+50 = 5×10^{100}+50$.

Comment: I got a different answer which matches the other answer posted

Comment: It's a good try, but you forgot about palindromes.

Comment: What about zeros that are neither trailing nor leading?